# The open source Xamarin.Android is missing mandroid

Tags: linux, xamarin, msbuild, mono, xamarin.android

I managed to compile the recently open sourced Xamarin.Android code from [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android) on Linux (current ubuntu) and tried to compile the sample, and got the following error:

```
$ tools/scripts/xabuild samples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 4.4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 5/5/2016 7:42:19 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/opt/xamarin/xamarin-android/samples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj" (default target(s)):
    Target _CreatePropertiesCache:
        Created directory "obj/Debug/"
    Target _BuildSdkCache:
: error XA0020: Could not find mandroid!
    Task "ResolveSdks" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_BuildSdkCache" in project "/opt/xamarin/xamarin-android/samples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj".-- FAILED
Done building project "/opt/xamarin/xamarin-android/samples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
```

Then I tried my actual app that I wanted to compile and got the same error.

It seems to be missing the "mandroid" file, which is called mandroid.exe under windows and is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Msbuild\Xamarin\Android\mandroid.exe. It is 13 MB large and is a native executable (not .NET).

What am I doing wrong?

Miguel de Icaza stated years ago that they weren't planning on supporting Linux because there are too many flavors. Now that it's open source, it should be possible to compile and run it under Linux just like on OS X.

But I can't find any mandroid file anywhere in the source tree. There are a couple references to it but I don't know how to build it.

Best regards,

Hans

Comment: You should try ask on the mailing lists: http://open.xamarin.com/community

Comment: yeah this looks like a bug, don't post bugs in stackoverflow, use xamarin resources, such as http://bugzilla.xamarin.com